# How to get Facebook user email on server with php once I already have the access token

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login, facebook-access-token

I successfully got the access token from my Android app as such...

```
  fbbutton = (com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.fbbutton);
  fbbutton.setOnClickListener(this);
  fbbutton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("public_profile", "email"));
  callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
  fbbutton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {

    @Override
    public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
      GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(loginResult.getAccessToken(), new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {
          if (response.getError() != null) {

          } else {

            if ((email = object.optString("email")) != null) {

            } else {
              email = object.optString("id") + "@facebook.com";
            }
            editor.putString("ftoken", AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().toString());
            editor.apply();
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
          }
        }
      });
      Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
      parameters.putString("fields", "id, name, email"); // facebook parameters
      request.setParameters(parameters);
      request.executeAsync();

      // signed in UI
    }
```

I then successfully sent the access token to my server's php script.

I'm trying to get facebook to give me the user's email on the server side using the access token.

I'm trying as such...

```
        require_once __DIR__ . '/facebook-php-sdk-v4/src/Facebook/autoload.php';
```

(...)

```
        $fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
            'app_id' => '491680537671890',
            'app_secret' => 'abe9f51094b3d7c9edb3c28d102170a1',
            'default_graph_version' => 'v2.4'
        ]);
        fwrite($Handle, "point 1");

            $response = $fb->get('/me', $ftoken);

        //print_r($response);
        fwrite($Handle, "response:$response\n\n");
        $email = $response["email"];
        $userid = $email;
        fwrite($Handle, "email confirmed by facebook:[$email]\n\n");
```

But my php code only gets to "point 1".  So it is failing at the $fb->get stage.  What am I doing wrong?  Thanks for any help.

Edit:  I had forgotten to put a comma after the last array item

```
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
            'app_id' => '491680537671890',
            'app_secret' => 'abe9f51094b3d7c9edb3c28d102170a1',
            'default_graph_version' => 'v2.4',
        ]);
```

Now my code doesn't even get to **point 1**.

Edit:  Comma apparently doesn't matter but I took it out and I get to **point 1** again [I was mistaken and the comma really doesn't make a difference].  But the var_dumps come up empty as I programmed below..

```
$ftoken = $json->ftoken;
fwrite($Handle, "ftoken:$ftoken\r\n");
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
    'app_id' => '491680537671890',
    'app_secret' => 'abe9f51094b3d7c9edb3c28d102170a1',
    'default_graph_version' => 'v2.4'
]);
$vardump = var_dump($fb);
fwrite($Handle, "first vardump:$vardump\n\n");

$response = $fb->get('/me?fields=id,name', $ftoken);
$vardump = var_dump($response);
fwrite($Handle, "vardump:$vardump\n\n");
```

Edit: #3:  I implemented the following suggested code...

```
$ftoken = $json->ftoken;
        fwrite($Handle, "ftoken:$ftoken\r\n");
        $fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
                'app_id' => '491680537671890',
                'app_secret' => 'abe9f51094b3d7c9edb3c28d102170a1',
                'default_graph_version' => 'v2.4'
        ]);
        $fb->setDefaultAccessToken($ftoken);

        try {
            $response = $fb->get('/me');
            $userResponse = $response->getGraphUser();
        } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
            // When Graph returns an error
            $userResponse = 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
            // When validation fails or other local issues
            $userResponse = 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        }finally{
            fwrite($Handle, "response:$userResponse\n\n");
            }
```

and I get ...

```
response:Graph returned an error: Invalid OAuth access token.
```

So my token seems to be the incorrect type?

Edit: #4:  I went to the facebook object debug page and entered the token...

```
Access Token Info
App ID  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx : recipes
User ID
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx : Rxxn Kxxm
User last installed this app via API v2.x
Issued  1451792399 (20 hours ago)
Expires 1456976399 (in about 2 months)
Valid   True
Origin  Mobile Web Faceweb
Scopes  email, public_profile
```

So there shouldn't be any real problem with the token.  I'm stumped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try the following

```
$ftoken = $json->ftoken;
fwrite($Handle, "ftoken:$ftoken\r\n");
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
        'app_id' => '491680537671890',
        'app_secret' => 'abe9f51094b3d7c9edb3c28d102170a1',
        'default_graph_version' => 'v2.4'
]);
$fb->setDefaultAccessToken($ftoken);

try {
    $response = $fb->get('/me');
    $userResponse = $response->getGraphUser();
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
    // When Graph returns an error
    $userResponse = 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
    // When validation fails or other local issues
    $userResponse = 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
}finally{
    fwrite($Handle, "response:$userResponse\n\n");
}
```

and see what we get...

**Make sure your domain is in your app settings!**

Comment: Tried it and same result.

Comment: Please share what the var_dump of $response is after it runs.

Comment: The var_dump was empty.

Comment: You shouldnt need a comma after the last array item.

Comment: What is the var_dump or $fb after you attempt to initialize it?

Comment: var_dump on $fb also empty.  please see second edit to make sure I'm var_dumping properly.

Comment: To var dump you should be doing

die(var_dump($fb));

see my edit

Comment: I'm logging in with my android app, successfully getting the facebook email and access token there.  Then I successfully sent the token to the server and am trying to get the email with that token.  I can't see the output of var_dump unless I print it to a file somehow because my app is calling the server script.

Comment: In that case if $fb is empty it sounds like you're not even getting the Facebook Object initialized correctly which is odd.  Not sure where to go from that point.  $fb should return some sort of success to you that you can act on and then do your graph call.

Comment: Ok thanks,  I will double check to make sure I have the facebook SDK installed correctly.

Comment: At further inspection, I had to tweek your code.  After the tweeks I get the error in my "Edit: #3:"  above.  My token is somehow not valid.

Comment: Hmm well thats something. Have you verified that $ftoken is not empty?  Maybe try with passing the token with your /me call like you were earlier?  Also if your app is in development mode, the account youre using to receive the access token must either be and admin or a tester account for the app or FB will reject it.

Comment: You may be able to test also by going to the Graph API Explorer and generating an access token there for testing and temporarily hardcoding that access_token into your PHP to see if there's an issue with your token.  Remember: email is an extended permission.

Comment: Thanks.. I'm going to investigate this token business soon.  I wonder if it is because I converted the token to a string before sending.

Comment: I went to https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/ and put in my token.  The token seems good.  I'm stumped.

Comment: Hmm perhaps try doing a $ftoken = json_encode($ftoken); before sending it through?

Comment: Is the domain your sending the request from in the app settings as being an acceptable domain?

Comment: Dude that was it!  I added the domain, logged out, back in, sync.... worked!  Thanks so much!

Comment: put it in your answer and i'll accept it so people can see it easier.